# Set a Required Field in QGIS Edit Form

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to make a field required in a QGIS Edit Form?

Answer (score 4):

Based on Nathan Woodrow's [code example](http://woostuff.wordpress.com/2011/09/05/qgis-tips-custom-feature-forms-with-python-logic/) and some digging through the docs and bug trackers (connecting buttons to other QT Signals [seems to be broken](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/issues/575) in QGIS?) I came to this solution, which works in QGIS 2.14.2, at least in the *Add Feature* attributes dialog (haven't tested other possibilities):

```python
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import QgsMessageLog

myRequiredfield = None
myDialog = None
buttonBox = None

def formOpen(dialog, layerid, featureid):
    global myDialog
    global myRequiredfield
    global buttonBox
    myDialog = dialog

    # replace "required_field" with your field's name/id
    myRequiredfield = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit, "required_field")
    buttonBox = dialog.findChild(QDialogButtonBox, "buttonBox")

    # block the default signals, means we have to (re-)bind our own functions
    buttonBox.blockSignals(True)
    bnOk = buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
    bnOk.clicked.connect(validate)
    bnCancel = buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
    bnCancel.clicked.connect(myDialog.parent().reject)

def validate():
    # Make sure that the name field isn't empty.
    # changed text.length() to len(text) because QGIS switched to unicode at some point
    if not len(myRequiredfield.text()) > 0 or myRequiredfield.text() == u'NULL':
        msgBox = QMessageBox()
        msgBox.setText("field can not be null.")
        msgBox.exec_()
    else:
        # Return the form as accepted to QGIS.
        myDialog.parent().accept()
```

Comment: have you tried this using qgis 2.6? the logic in this blog worked for me up until 2.4, but it doesn't seem to anymore.

Comment: @user25976 If you are still looking, I updated my answer with some working code for QGIS 2.14